# Django admin link at user model from another in list

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

In my django admin i have a model that link to user, i would have n my list create a link for pass to related user id editing page directly from connected models, i do:

```
class a_cards(models.Model):
    CK_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Ambassador'),
        ('M', 'Medico'),
        ('P', 'Paziente'),
        ('S', 'Senator'),
    )

    c_num = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,
                         null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Numero card")
    c_data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    c_type = models.CharField(
    max_length=1, choices=CK_CHOICES, verbose_name="Tipo utenza")
    c_email = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,
                         null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Notifica Email")
    c_agente = models.ForeignKey(AgenteProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True, blank=True, related_name="ag_id", verbose_name="Agente")
    c_user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Cliente" )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cards'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cards'

    def user_link(self):
        if self.c_user:
            return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=(self.c_user.id,)) , escape(self.c_user))

    user_link.allow_tags = True
    user_link.short_description = "User" 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c_num
```

in admin:

```
class cardAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    list_filter = ('c_type',)
    list_display = ('c_num', 'c_data', 'c_type', 'c_agente', 'user_link',)
    ...
```

but when i open my admin page i see the correct link but not in  libk form:

[image]

where is the error?
why i can't have clickable link?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [`format_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) for building HTML contents. so refactor your url generator method like;

```
class a_cards(models.Model):
    ....
    
    def user_link(self):
        if self.c_user:
            return format_html('<a href="{url}">{text}</a>', url=reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=(self.c_user.id,)), text=self.c_user)
        return "-"

user_link.short_description = "User"
user_link.allow_tags = True
```

from the docs;

> All args and kwargs are passed through conditional_escape() before being passed to str.format().

so you do not need to specify extra `escape()`.